# Getting new Refresh Token when after revoking access permission

Tags: permissions, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have implemented Google oauth2 server flow for web. Now I'm testing it. as I have already given permission to my Application in my own google account I'm not getting a Refresh Token (that is completely normal) but I'm revoking access to my app and trying to sign in again but still I don't refresh token (I get access token and other parameters).

I tried removing cookies after revoking access but it didn't help either. Why I don't get a new access token (while google document says that I will get a new refresh token if the access permission is revoked).

**Note That:** I don't want to use `access_type=offline` as I want the users see that my website is only asking for email and basic profile information.

**Update:**
I found this in google documentation:

> Note that there are limits on the number of refresh tokens that will be issued; one limit per client/user combination, and another per user across all clients. You should save refresh tokens in long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. If your application requests too many refresh tokens, it may run into these limits, in which case older refresh tokens will stop working.

And I think that I have reached the per client/user limit. Does anybody know how to increase this limit?

Comment: AFAIK you have to use `access_type=offline`; I don't see how you got the initial refresh token if you haven't specified that.

Comment: @HansZ. the refresh token is given if you use access_type=offline or the first time granting access to the application

Comment: according to this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline you need to specify `access_type=offline` also the first time, that's my experience as well

Comment: @HansZ. in the same link you provided search for this: >If this is the first time the application has exchanged an authorization code for a user, then the response includes an access token and a refresh token

Comment: that section comes only after the explanation of adding `access_type=offline` and it also says "The normal and default style of access is called online."

Comment: @HansZ. after lots of searches I got to the point that you are right, I don't know how did I get those refresh tokens with access_type=online though